# PageViewController hosted within a Container within a StackView/ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a ViewController with the following hierarchy using xcode 8 and swift 3:

`View
    ScrollView
        StackView
            Container View
                PageViewController
                PageControll
            TableView`

My intent is to allow vertical scrolling via the ScrollView/StackView and this is working fine.

The container view hosts a PageViewController and PageControl both of which are created programmatically vs. the Storyboard.

My problem is that I can't find a way to support the vertical scrolling of the entire page while also supporting the swiping left/right within the PageViewController.

If I add the PageViewController.view to the master page via:

`self.view.addSubview((self.pageViewController?.view)!)`

The swiping between pages in the PageViewController works fine but the upper portion of the page doesn't scroll with the scrollview.

If I add the PageViewController.view to the Container via:

`self.containerView.addSubview((self.pageViewController?.view)!)`

While the vertical scrolling works fine but the swiping left and right over the pageviews doesn't.

Footnote that this entire ViewController is hosted within a NavigationController as a drill in from a feed type view.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: I was able to get both scrolling gestures working by adding the pageViewController's view as a subview of the UIScrollView instead of the master or containerView. 

`self.scrollView.addSubview((self.pageViewController?.view)!)`

That was the only option I hadn't attempted:)

Comment: Hello did you solve your problem? I'm facing it right now.

Comment: @Erumaru, I moved away from using Scroll & Stack Views to using a  TableView with custom TableViewCells that host the items I want to allow to swipe horizontally.  This solved my scrolling vertically issues and ended up being much easier to code and handle orientation changes.   The other benefit is the Custom TableViewCells can then be used in other parts of the app without much effort.